# How can I show a new view controller after 3 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to show a new ViewController after I clicked on a button, but not directly. After clicking the button I want to wait 3 seconds an after the 3 seconds I want the new ViewController

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 3):

**Add delay on click of button:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
   // Your code with navigate to another controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scheduled timer to fire off a function after a given timeInterval.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(showVC), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


@objc func showVC() {
    //navigate to your desired VC
}
```

Answer (score -1):

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { in [weak,self]

// Your code with navigate to another controller
// weak self becouse may be your current viewcontroller is dinit

}

Answer (score -1):

Inside the button action create a timer:

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
_ = Timer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(showVC), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Then add an objective-C selector that will present the next View Controller when called by the timer 3 seconds later.

```
@objc func showVC() {
    let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```